# SQLAlchemy: как правильно добавить сортировку для функции extract?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

У меня есть такая функция для SQLAlchemy:

```
count_data_for_interval_clicks = db.session.query(func.count(Clicks.id).label('count'),
                                                          extract('year', Clicks.datetime).label('year'),
                                                          extract('month', Clicks.datetime).label('month'),
                                                          extract('day', Clicks.datetime).label('day')). \
            filter(Clicks.site_id == site_id, Clicks.click == True). \
            group_by(extract('year', Clicks.datetime),
                     extract('month', Clicks.datetime),
                     extract('day', Clicks.datetime)). \
            order_by(year.desc(), month.desc(), day.desc())
```

Сортировка сейчас не работает. Выдает ошибку: `"name 'year' is not defined"`

Ошибку понимаю, но не знаю, почему не принимает название колонки. И как исправить тоже не понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

```
count_data_for_interval_clicks = db.session.query(func.count(Clicks.id).label('count'),
                                                          extract('year', Clicks.datetime).label('year'),
                                                          extract('month', Clicks.datetime).label('month'),
                                                          extract('day', Clicks.datetime).label('day')). \
            filter(Clicks.site_id == site_id, Clicks.click == True). \
            group_by(extract('year', Clicks.datetime),
                     extract('month', Clicks.datetime),
                     extract('day', Clicks.datetime)). \
            order_by(extract('year', Clicks.datetime).desc(), extract('month', Clicks.datetime).desc(), extract('day', Clicks.datetime).desc())
```